# Having trouble when migrating changes to the database - Python/Django

Tags: django, sqlite

I was making some changes to the database in my project but i am facing some problems, it appears to not be a column in one of my tables but there it is, don't know what may be the cause of the problem, i'm not sure if it has to be with the onetoonefield relationships or what just broke it up entirely.

## Models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BloodType(models.Model):
    Tipo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tipo


class Gender(models.Model):
    Genero = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Genero

class Nationality(models.Model):
    Nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nacionalidad

class CivilStatus(models.Model):
    Estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Estado

class InsuranceCompany(models.Model):
    Compania = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Compania

class Policy(models.Model):
    Tipo_Poliza = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Tipo_Poliza

class Insurance(models.Model):
    Aseguradora = models.OneToOneField(InsuranceCompany,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Tipo_de_Poliza =  models.OneToOneField(Policy, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Numero_de_poliza = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Vencimiento = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Aseguradora) + ' ' + str(self.Tipo_de_Poliza)

class Patient(models.Model):
    Codigo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Fecha_Nacimiento = models.DateField()
    Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)
    Correo = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    Expediente = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Tipo_sangre = models.OneToOneField(BloodType,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Peso = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Estatura = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Genero = models.OneToOneField(Gender,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Nacionalidad = models.OneToOneField(Nationality,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Estado_civil = models.OneToOneField(CivilStatus,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Ocupacion = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Lugar_de_procedencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lugar_de_residencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Seguro = models.OneToOneField(Insurance,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,default='No tiene seguro.')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombre + ' ' + self.Apellidos
```

## Error

```
OperationalError at /admin/patients/patient/
no such column: patients_patient.Seguro_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/patients/patient/
Django Version: 2.2.12
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: patients_patient.Seguro_id
Exception Location: /Users/lralcocer/PycharmProjects/MedTracker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 383
Python Executable:  /Users/lralcocer/PycharmProjects/MedTracker/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/lralcocer/PycharmProjects/MedTracker/medtracker',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/lralcocer/PycharmProjects/MedTracker/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 7 May 2020 06:53:16 +0000
```

## Commands Errors

```
 #Make Migrations
(venv) MacBook-Pro:medtracker lralcocer$ python manage.py makemigrations patients
No changes detected in app 'patients'

#Python manage.py migrate
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'UNDEFINED'
```

Comment: what is the output of `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands?

Comment: Omie, i already editted the question, in the last part you can see the errors each command returns:)

Comment: Luis, you see the error right there :) Your migrate command did not succeed, hence the column `Seguro = models.OneToOneField ...` did not get created in the db. (`seguro_id` is the actual column name django creates for relationships). You are getting value error because `default='No tiene seguro.'`. Note that, `seguro_id` will be of type integer as it's a relationship. And when django is trying to migrate, for existing records, it's going to set that default value you have provided. String can't fit in int column. You should probably remove default value and allow null for that field.

Comment: I also tried deleting that specific column and trying to make the migrations, still did not succeed!:(

Comment: I also deleted the default value and still migrate is not succeeding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often Django can't catch that you have changed the type of a field (for example, when you change primary key, foreign keys will be left with old type). I have not the best solution, but if you have no important data in that field, it should work:

1. Remove the field from the model.
2. Remove last migration file (that causes the error)
3. Make migrations, migrate
4. Add the deleted field to the model
5. Make migrations, migrate again